# Drag and Drop file inside a Table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, angular

In my Angular 5 Application i have a HTML Table which will be filled by a JSON Webservice Object which contains Details from a file. The JSON would look something like this.

```
{
    "id": 1337,
    "path": "somepath",
    "filename": "Test_File",
    "filetype": "pdf",
    "description": "Test File",
    "date": "2013-04-12T13:10:04.717",
    "file": "base64encoded"
    "createtionDate": "2013-04-12T13:10:04.717",
    "createdBy": "MasterOfTheUniverse",
}
```

And the Table:

```
 <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>File</th>
          <th>Filename</th>
          <th>Created By</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td><a><img (click)="openFile(id.id)" #id id="{{file.id}}" 
          attr.data-basecode="{{file.file}}" 
          attr.data-filename="{{file.filename}}" 
          attr.data-filetype="{{file.filetype}}" 
          src="assets/layout/images/{{file.filetype}}.png"></a></td>
          <td>{{file.filename}}</td>
          <td>{{file.createdBy}}</td>
        </tr>
      </tobdy>
    </table>
```

I can open a File by clicking on the Img inside the Table. I also can upload a file and send it to the backend via a Input type="file" Element and its Explorer selection. 
Now here is what i want to achive:
I want to drag and drop a file inside the table to have the same effect as if i would select a file with the input field.

Is this possible ? 
If so how could a solution look like and what would be the best approach?